# videojs plugin version 4.1.0 not working on ie8 and below

Tags: javascript, jquery

The Below code is working fine on chrome/firefox/ie9/ie10.

This is not working on ie8 and below. As per the plugin fallback of flash should work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Video.js | HTML5 Video Player</title>
        <!-- Chang URLs to wherever Video.js files will be hosted -->
        <link href="video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <!-- video.js must be in the <head> for older IEs to work. -->
        <script src="video.js"></script>

        <!-- Unless using the CDN hosted version, update the URL to the Flash SWF -->
        <script>
            videojs.options.flash.swf = "http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10414458/video-js.swf";
        </script>


    </head>
    <body>

        <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none" width="640" height="360"
               poster="poster.png" data-setup='{ "controls": true, "autoplay": true, "preload": "auto" }'>
            <source src="demo.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
        </video>

    </body>
</html>
```

Some one help me solving this problem Thanks.

Comment: How about you help us first? Check your error console and other things you should be doing to try and fix your own problem and post your findings here

Comment: FYI there are no errors in console sorry..according to plugin that should add and object tag by itself and load the swf file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry,
I was running this code locally without any server so the plugin didnt work as expected.
When I put the same code on server It worked Like Gem :) :)